# Can anyone identify this instrument part and what instrument it comes from?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Can anyone identify this instrument part and what instrument it comes from?[image]

Comment: A better picture might help.

Comment: Chances to keep a question like this active increase by provision of context.  E.g., found in an analytical lab performing soil analyses; the nozzle-like shape has a fine opening (or not), material is of (magnetic?) metal, and -- like for a crime investigation -- *add* a scale to the picture.  This could be a ruler (preferred), or (if small) look into your pocket for a well known coin to be put next to the unknown object. If the camera used possesses a macro function (i.e., yields a better focus for objects in proximity), activate it.

Answer (score 7):

It is the inside of a centrifuge where the rotor gets attached (the top spins, and the two pins ensure proper seat of the rotor on the conical piece). Here is a better picture of the inside of a Sorvall RC-5C Plus Floor Centrifuge, with the hands serving as scale bar. This is partially disassembled to show how one would change the motor brushing.

[image]

Screenshot from https://youtu.be/rO1q2eHTyJ0?t=434

If this is for a trivia game, I want to be credited. If this is for some crazy exam question, I'm sorry I helped cheating.